# MenuItem.mActionProvider is null

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I add following Menu item:

on my mainactivity's `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`:

the `mediaRouteItem.getActionView()` can get the button successfully.but the `ActionProvider` is null. Please help a introduction why. Thanks a lot!

```
<item
android:id="@+id/action_mediaroute01"
android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton"
android:showAsAction="always"
android:title="@string/hello_world"/>
```

-

```
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem mediaRouteItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_mediaroute01 );
    MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider = (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteItem);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got the issue point after researching. Should not use android:actionProviderClass when we want to use objects in support library. Should take "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" namespace for the actionproviderClass attributes in menu item xml

Comment: Had the same problem with NullPointerException. I missed to extend my Activity from ActionBarActivity. The Android doc says:"To use the media route action provider, the activity must be a subclass of ActionBarActivity from the android.support.v7.appcompat support library."