# Chromecast Nullpointer exception for MediaRouter

Tags: android, chromecast

I am trying to put the Chromecast icon in my menu item. I have the following defined in my menu layout.

```
<item
android:id="@+id/media_route_menu_item"
android:title="Stream your videos!"
android:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider"
android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

In my onCreateOptionsMenu() method I do the following as advised in the official chromecast tutorial.

```
   1.   mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
   2.  mediaRouteActionProvider =
            (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
   3. mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
```

This gives me this error in line 3 above.

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(android.support.v7.media.MediaRouteSelector)' on a null object reference
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone help me out?

EDIT:

This is my mMediaRouteSelector:

```
         mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("[MY APP ID]"))
            .build();
```

Comment: And what is your mMediaRouteSelector?

Comment: Your activity must extend ActionBarActivity

Comment: It is extending actionbaractivity

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22030832/956415

Comment: possible duplicate of [MenuItem.mActionProvider is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22016757/menuitem-mactionprovider-is-null)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, these types of errors happen because proguard changes the name of the object and/or functions.

One possible solution is to add these to your progaurd configuration files:

```
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.internal.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }
```